# Dissolve feature in geopandas based on multiple attributes

Tags: fields-attributes, geopandas, dissolve, pandas

It is possible to dissolve features in GeoPandas based on the attribute field. However, I would like to know how to dissolve features in GeoPandas using at least two attribute fields. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Have an attempt with the groupby examples in https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/185, you can pass a list of columns to groupby.  Then if you have any problems, edit your question and post your code and any exception text.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I am not understanding the context of the original question but I got here via a Google search. The linked GitHub thread in the OP question comments seems over-engineerd. It seems to me that this can actually be done quite easily:

```
attrs = ["attr0", "attr1", "attr2"]
gdf_dissolved = gdf.dissolve(by=attrs, as_index=False)
```

`as_index=False` stops the grouping fields from being used as the index in `gdf_dissolved`.