# How to dissolve two geodataframes, using multiple columns to group by

Tags: python, geopandas, dissolve

I want to dissolve a dataframe grouped by two columns. However, in the [documentation of the Dissolve](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.dissolve.html) function only one column is provided:

```
GeoDataFrame.dissolve(by=None, aggfunc='first', as_index=True,
level=None, sort=True, observed=False, dropna=True)
```

The columns of the dataframe can be thought of like this:

> State, Districts, City, Number_Inhabitantes

Instead of the syntax given in the documentation, I would like to do something similar to this, to get the number of Inhabitants per District instead of having the Number of Inhabitantes per city:

```
GeoDataFrame.dissolve(by= "State"&"Districts",aggfunc={"Number_Inhabitantes": "count"} )
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is pretty straightforward : the `by` argument can be a list of column names, even though the doc doesn't mention this.
So to obtain "the number of Inhabitants per District", you may use the following :

```py
gdf.dissolve(by=['States', 'Districts'], aggfunc={'Number_Inhabitantes': 'sum'})
```

N.B.: this will result in a multi-indexed dataframe.

Comment: Also see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368314/dissolve-feature-in-geopandas-based-on-multiple-attributes?rq=1

Comment: Thank you! That was quite easy ...